# ¿Como puedo trabajar con un documento xml en base de datos?

Tags: mysql, sql

Buen dia, estoy trabajando con un xml el cual estaba codificado, logre decodificarlo y ahora debo extraer cierta informacion que contiene el doc. para pasarlo a otra tabla diferente, mi pregunta es como debo trabajar con un query para poder buscar el dato que me interesa.
e intentado con varios querys que e visto en internet pero no se bien en que estoy fallando

un ejemplo del xml es este:

```
<section id="2">    
<name>Detalle del Servicio</name>  <br>
<field id="1"><name>Circuito</name><content type="string" input-type="text">
<option></option></content></field>
<field id="2"><name>Nodo</name><content type="string" input-type="text">
<option></option></content></field>
<field id="3"><name>Tipo Tecnologia</name><content type="integer" input-type="select">
<option value="2" info="">Seleccionar</option>
<option value="0" info="">Frame Relay</option>
<option value="1" info="">TDM</option>
<option value="3" info="">CPA</option>
<option value="4" info="">MPLS</option>
<option value="5" info="">L2L</option>
<option value="6" info="">L2l Estrella</option>
<option value="7" info="selected">Internet negocios</option>
<option value="8" info="">FTTX</option>
<option value="10" info="">Internet Dedicado</option>
<option value="9" info="">Internet SAM PMP</option></content></field>
<field id="4"><name>Acceso (KBps)</name><content type="integer" input-type="text">
<option>10240</option></content></field>
<field id="5"><name>CIR (KBps)</name><content type="integer" input-type="text">
<option>10240</option></content></field>
<field id="6"><name>Es Nodo Principal?</name><content type="integer" input-type="select">
<option value="0" info="selected">No</option>
<option value="1" info="">Si</option></content></field></section>
```

suponiendo que quiero sacar el dato con el info ="selected" en la field id="3" Tipo Tecnologia

e intentado con este query pero el mismo me lanza error:

DECLARE doc_xml xml;
SELECT
@doc_xml = CONVERT(xml, doc_xml)
FROM
xml

SELECT
Tabla.Col.value('@name','VARCHAR(50)') AS 'name'
FROM
@doc_xml.nodes('//section/name') Tabla(Col);

mi tabla se llama xml, y el campo que contiene el documento se llama doc_xml

---

este es el error que me indica al ejecutar el query

DECLARE doc_xml xml

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE doc_xml xml' at line 1
> Time: 0s

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Nos decis que tenes un error, y te creemos. Pero es mejor que nos muestres que error te da (como texto) y cual es la linea o el contexto donde te da el mismo.

Comment: buen dia, este es el error que me da al ejecutar el query

Comment: DECLARE doc_xml xml
> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE doc_xml xml' at line 1
> Time: 0s